# Cordova - issue adding plugins in iOS

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am getting some strange issue while adding plugin in iOS using CLI. Executed below commands in Terminal,

1. cordova create Documents/Work/hello com.example.hello hello world
2. cordova platform add ios
3. cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
4. cordova build

But the build is failing & showing the below message,

*error: no such file or directory: '/Users/gtmac/Documents/Work/hello/platforms/ios/helloworld/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.device/CDVDevice.m'
clang: error: no input files*

** BUILD FAILED **

When I add any plugin, .m & .h files are not getting copied to the Platforms/Plugins folder. But the files are present in the Plugins folder in the root directory.

Comment: There was a known issue with a lower-case in the project's name. So try to keep the project's name as **Hello world** once?

Comment: Yes. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this known issue with Cordova, where the build fails if the project's name has the *first letter in lowercase*. It has been reported back in 2014, but still not fixed, nor mentioned in the docs/no specification in the errors.

So keep the app's project name starting with an uppercase.

Comment: Please, where do you change the projects name? In what folder, what file?